# ShareThis plugin on WordPress MU - default in all blogs

Tags: php, wordpress

I have one instance of Wordpress Multiuser and need [ShareThis](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/share-this/) plugin to be automatically activated in all new created blogs.

I've seen a post:

Plugins placed in `wp-content/mu-plugins` are automatically enabled for all blogs in the system. They cannot be turned off by the users.

When putting the plugin files into root blog (`/plugins/` folder), the plugin is functional, but when putting it into `/mu-plugins` , the plugin is not working.

What else do i need to do to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugins put in `/mu-plugins` cannot be in folders.
`/mu-plugins` can only contain plugin files like `what-ever-plugin.php`.

Answer (score 0):

The mu-plugins directory will not read plugins in a subfolder, so your ShareThis plugin must be modified to individual file to work.

Any plugin files in a subfolder will be ignored unless included in the primary plugin file.